# Short Hand JavaScript IF Else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have this shorthand version of a JavaScript if else function and I am wondering how would it look if it was normal if else:

```
var criteriaField = criteria.hasOwnProperty('searchTerm') ? 'name': 'price';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look like this:

```
var criteriaField;
if (criteria.hasOwnProperty('searchTerm')) {
  criteriaField = 'name';
} else {
  criteriaField = 'price';
}
```

You should read more about the ternary operator (`?`) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (criteria.hasOwnProperty('searchTerm')) var criteriaField = 'name';
else var criteriaField = 'price';
```

Answer (score 0):

The term before the `?` operator is the condition, followed by the value if the condition evaluates to true, and then to false. SO, as an if-else statement, it could be written as:

```
var criteriaField;
if (criteria.hasOwnProperty('searchTerm')) {
    criteriaField = 'name';
} else{
    criteriaField = 'price';
}
```